# How to save tasks.json and launch.json for later use in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have configured default tasks.json and launch.json given in C++ extension for current workspace
I want to save these .json files in VScode for future use and don't want to copy or modify it every time I make a new workspace.

How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: create a snippet for it

Comment: I made a snippet for .json file but was not able to use it in tasks.json or launch.json

Comment: in which file did you put the snippet

Comment: i made the snippet using an extension and saved it as cpp_project.json

Comment: save the snippet in the `cpp.json` global snippet file. `File` | `Preferences` | `User Snippets`

Comment: I tried but it does not show up in tasks.json or launch.json and for .cpp file it just copies the body in snippet into that .cpp file

Comment: show the filenames and there contents. You need to type the snippet prefix and hit TAB